# How to reuse app's toolbar in a library's activity?

Tags: java, android

I need app's main activity toolbar functions such as jump to other activity or logout,and i want add a button on main activity toolbar to use in a library's activity. Is this feasible? Can main activity toolbar get the library activity's data? I have no idea but to ask for help.

Comment: Yes, I guess its possible... Make a Constructor with AppCompatActivity as its parameter then find `mActivity.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);` the only downside is that the library user must use (R.id.toolbar) or you can also create a method like setToolbar(Toolbar toolbar) in library & access the Activity's toolbar!

Comment: @DarShan,Thank you for your answer.